# RemoveEventListener is not working after removing the parent view

Tags: events, button, addeventlistener, coronasdk

I have implemented a function with that i have added a view with the some button as well as added Eventlistener .

with the button listener i transitioned to another view and removed the last view but still the button listener is active .

```
 function loadingMenu()

     playBtn = display.newImage('play-btn.png', 170, 130)
    playBtn:addEventListener( "tap", listener )

    instructionBtn = display.newImage('instructions-btn.png', 150, 164)
   -- instructionBtn:addEventListener( "tap", instructionListener )

     creditBtn = display.newImage('credits-btn.png', 180, 201)
    --creditBtn:addEventListener( "tap",ceditsListener )

    titleBg = display.newImage('background-with-title.png')

   --titleView = display:newGroup()
     titleView = display.newGroup(titleBg, playBtn, instructionBtn,creditBtn)

end


function listener(event) 
      if titleView ~= nil then 
        playBtn:removeEventListener( "tap", listener ) 
        transition.to(titleView, {time = 300, y = -titleView.width, onComplete = function() --startButtonListeners('rmv') --titleView:removeSelf() display.remove(titleView) titleView = nil end}) 

       end 
       return true 
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to fix your code that has lots of random comments on it and I failed to understand it.

Please first fix the code, clean it, make proper indenting, and then I can try to understand it and see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will work...

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    local playBtn,instructionBtn,creditBtn,titleBg,titleView
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function newfunction()
      print("inside newfunction...")
    end
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function listener()
       print("inside listener...")
       if titleView ~= nil then 
               playBtn:removeEventListener( "tap", listener ) 
               transition.to(titleView, {time = 300, y = -titleView.width, onComplete = newfunction()}) --startButtonListeners('rmv') --titleView:removeSelf() display.remove(titleView) titleView = nil end}) 
       end 
       return true 
    end
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   function loadingMenu()
      playBtn = display.newImage("play-btn.png", 170, 130)
      instructionBtn = display.newImage("instructions-btn.png", 150, 164)
      creditBtn = display.newImage("credits-btn.png", 180, 201)
      titleBg = display.newImage("background-with-title.png")
      titleView = display.newGroup(titleBg, playBtn, instructionBtn,creditBtn)

      playBtn:addEventListener( "tap", listener )
   end
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  loadingMenu()
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```